# C++ pointer not working

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to learn linked list using c++. Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void show(node *head)
{
    node *n;
    n=head;
    while(n)
    {
        cout<<n->data<<' ';
        n=n->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void insert(node *list,int x)
{
    list->data=x;
    node *t=new node;
    list->next=t;
    list=t;
}
int main()
{
    node *head,*t,*list=new node;
    head=list;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insert(list,i+1);
    }
    show(head);
}
```

I have pointed head to the memory list is pointing to at beginning, but after insert the call of `insert` function, `head` points to the memory that `list` is pointing to, but was it suppose to happen. Isn't head suppose to remain unchanged?

Comment: what is supposed to remain constant?

Comment: `list=t;` if you want this to have any effect, you should pass-by-reference the pointer. `node* list` the pointer is passed by value, ie you can change the value the pointer is pointing to, but changes to the pointer will stay local to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert()` when called repeatedly on the same `list` makes `list->next` point to a new `node`.

That new node is not initialised, so dereferencing its `next` pointer (as occurs in `show()`) gives undefined behaviour.   As soon as code has undefined behaviour, all bets are off - anything can happen.

The net effect is that, because of how `insert()` behaves, `show()` will exhibit undefined behaviour.

Since `list` is passed by value, assigning to it in `insert()` has no effect.   That assignment is not visible to `main()`.

The previous node pointed to by `list->next` is also lost (not released, no longer accessible).

`main()` also leaves `list` uninitialised, so using its members (in `insert()` or `show()`) causes undefined behaviour, even if problems above are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the `insert()` function.

1) The wrong node's `data` is set. Instead of setting the new node's `data` to the value being inserted, the code sets the existing head node's `data` to the new value. The new node's value remains uninitialized.

2) The `list` parameter is passed by value to `insert()`. Which means that:

```
list=t;
```

accomplishes absolutely nothing. Because `list` is passed by value, this sets the `insert()` function's `list` to the new list head. Unfortunately, when `insert()` returns, the new list head gets discarded, and the original `list` in `main()` remains unchanged.

Either `list` must be passed to `insert()` by reference, or `insert()` should explicitly `return` the new `list`.

Additionally:

`main()` allocates the initial head node, and leaves it completely uninitialized. This link-list will always have one extra node whose `data` is never initialized. This is probably not what was intended. The correct approach is to set the empty list's head pointer to `NULL`, an empty list, and the first `insert()` should then correctly instantiate the first node in the link list.

There's one other thing that's wrong with the existing code that creates the extra, uninitialized node, that makes it clearly a bug: the extra node's `next` pointer is also not initialized. Attempting to walk the resulting link list will result in undefined behavior, and a likely crash.